# Can a non-admin upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

Since KB3095675 it seems, that Microsoft is really, really forcing the update to Windows 10 regardless whether the user wants it or not. From what I've heard, if the user doesn't actively re-schedule the update and - for example - simply closes that window, it will eventually happen.

There are quite a few pcs in my family which I administer and everyone except me is using a normal user account. This is primarily so that people don't accidentially do something bad. Especially my grand mother is really happy knowing, that unless she enters a password at a certain occasion, nothing really bad is likely to happen. Whenever she is prompted for that password, she always declines and waits for my next visit, which is absolutely great from my point of view.

My question is, whether she will be prompted for an admin password before the upgrade to Windows 10 starts. Ordinary windows updates are set to automatically install. I honestly hope that the answer is "Yes, she will be prompted.", but I haven't found any reliable information on that.

In case she won't be prompted, the next question arises: Can an ordinary user without an admin password re-schedule the upgrade? In other words: Is administrative action required to prevent that upgrade?

Comment: Yes a normal user will be able to ignore the prompts and eventually the upgrade will happen without any additional prompts. So if you want to block the upgrade, you should modify the registry, to block the upgrade and the GWX application.  You can also just cancel the upgrade, if you just close the window, that does not cancel it.  Don't forget after July 31 2016 you will have to pay for the upgrade if you chance your mind.

Comment: Not was I was hoping for, but I'm not surprised, either. Thanks for the answer. Just "treated" my three most important machines. And yes, I'm aware of the consequences...